# Rewrite and silex in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, silex

I'm completely lost after try and fail for hours with this...

I have an application with Silex inside a dir called "/backend".

The silex app is working correctly in "domain.com/backend/web" and I need to have it working in "domain.com/backend".

I have two .htaccess working, one in /backend and other in /backend/web

This is the .htaccess in /backend:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /backend/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is the one in /backend/web:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

This is the .htaccess located in / (root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess located in /backend/web

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This should do the job for you!